# Alter line spacing within entries using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-spacing

I'm using biblatex, with the biber backend on pdflatex.

The default line-spacing in my document is double spaced and the line-spacing in my bibliography is also double spaced. How can I make the spacing *within* individual entries single spaced while keeping the spacing *between* entries as it is (double spaced).

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution:
Using `setspace` package.

```
{\singlespacing\printbibliography}
```

achieves the desired results.